# Extract Text from BR tags

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have been able to extract text using Selenium before, however I'am having trouble with just extracting the numbers between < BR  > tags. Here is a sample of the html code.

```
<DIV class="pagebodydiv">
    <TABLE  CLASS="datadisplaytable" SUMMARY="This table will display needed information." WIDTH="100%">
<TR>
<TD CLASS="nttitle" scope="colgroup" >Working Title</A></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD CLASS="ntdefault">
 Further information on subject
<BR>
    3.000
<BR>
    2.000  
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
More information
<BR>
<BR>
</TABLE>
```

So far I have tried using:

```
WebElement creditinfo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='pagebodydiv']/text()[preceding-sibling::br]
```

and `Elements numInfo = doc.select("br");`

However, I keep running into a NoSuchElementException error, an InvalidSelectorException error, or it just doesn't return anything. Any ideas on how I can get the information?

Answer (score 4):

You actually *can* select the text nodes between `<BR>` tags. In HTML (not XHTML) they act as self-closing tags (like `<br/>`). Based on that behaviour, you could select all text nodes that have a `<BR>` tag before and after it using:

```
//TABLE[@CLASS='datadisplaytable']/TR/TD[@CLASS="ntdefault"]
/text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::BR] 
        and following-sibling::node()[1][self::BR]]
```

That would select also the blank lines and the character text which is not a number.

You can get rid of the empty space nodes adding a `[normalize-space(.) != '']` to the end of the expression (which will now only return three nodes). And you can select *which* node you want using a positional predicate at the end of the expression (`[1]` to select the first node.

The expression below selects the text node containing the value `2.000`:

```
//TABLE[@CLASS='datadisplaytable']/TR/TD[@CLASS="ntdefault"]
/text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::BR] 
        and following-sibling::node()[1][self::BR]][normalize-space(.) != ''][2]
```

*Note:* I'm assuming your source actually has tag names in uppercase, since in XPath `<TD>` is not the same as `<td>`. I'm not sure how tolerant Selenium is about this when parsing HTML.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried both of your suggestions and still get a NoSuchElementException error. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. This is how I used the code: WebElement info = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//TABLE[@CLASS='datadisplaytable']/TR/TD[@CLASS='ntdefault']/text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::BR]and following-sibling::node()[1][self::BR]][normalize-space(.) != ''][2]")); ...BTW did you mean to put ntdefault in double quotes?

Comment: Simple and double quotes make no difference (since you are using double quotes to enclose the expression, you should use single quotes inside it). XPath in selenium operates differently with HTML, since it has to deal with tags that don't close, entities, etc, which would be invalid in XML. But if you have very bad HTML with unclosing `<td>`s and other elements which should close, it may break. In that case, you should try using an HTML parser (JSoup for example).

Comment: You can try simplifying that expression and see if it works. Try `//TD[@CLASS="ntdefault"]/text()[2]` which should return the second text node (which contains `3.000`)

Comment: Hmmm...still doesn't seem to work. There are multiple tables with the same class name, does that matter? I keep getting a InvalidSelectorException error.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about how Selenium supports XPath in HTML. I know that different Selenium implementations (RC, WebDriver, etc.) might treat nodes differently, so although the `text()[1]` expression is perfectly valid in XPath, it might fail in some Selenium implementations. Also, you should check if it really is case-insensitive. It most XPath implementations `td` won't match `TD`.

Comment: Its not case sensitive. Also, I removed /text()[2] from the xpath and was able to get the information and the two numbers. I will keep playing around with it and see if I can just select numbers I need.

Answer (score 1):

It may help :

```
  WebElement table =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='datadisplaytable']"));
   WebElement tbody=table.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));
   List<WebElement> rows=tbody.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
   System.out.println("Row  size:"+rows.size());
   ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

   for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++)
   {
     WebElement column = tbody.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='datadisplaytable']/tbody/tr[2]/td"));
     if(column.getText().trim().contains("."))
     {
        System.out.println("text : "+column.getText().trim());
        list.add(column.getText().trim());
     }

   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Praveen. This is giving me the information of the entire table. I'll keep playing around with it though. BTW do you know how to search different tables if they all have the same class name?

Comment: there must be some unique things about all different tables otherwise selenium wont be able to differentiate between different tables.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `BR` are not considered enclosing tags, and so you will not be able to extract the "enclosing text". You will probably have to extract the text enclosed in your `TD CLASS="ntdefault"`, where all the `BR`s are going to get translated into newlines. You will then have to perform string manipulation to extract only the parts you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the rest of the webpage contains multiple TD elements with the same class name. Do you know of a way I can move past the first TD element and gather text from the next one?

Comment: This is a new problem now! You will need to use correct selectors; I personally prefer XPath. Have a read here: http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html

Comment: I really like that website, thanks for the reference.