# Extract table data with same class names

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to extract data from tables in a webpage, but I keep pulling up the same information. For example I have each movie in an arraylist, but I want to match each movie with the relevant table data. The problem is, each table has the same class name. I am able to print each movie title, but I'am only pulling MovieOne's table information. Here is a sample of the HTML for movie one and two:

```
    <TH CLASS="ddtitle">MovieOne</TH>
        <TABLE  CLASS="datadisplaytable" ><CAPTION class="captiontext">Movies</CAPTION>
    <TR>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Genre</TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Time</TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Days</TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Where</TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Date Range</TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Seating</TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Actors</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">Action</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">10:00 am - 12:00 pm</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">SMTWTHFSA</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">AMC Showplace</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">Aug 20, 2014 - Sept 12, 2014</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">Reservations</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">Will Ferrel (<ABBR title= "Primary">P</ABBR>)  target="Will Ferrel" ></TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
<TH CLASS="ddtitle">MovieTwo</TH>
        <TABLE  CLASS="datadisplaytable" ><CAPTION class="captiontext">Movies</CAPTION>
    <TR>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Genre</TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Time</TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Days</TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Where</TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Date Range</TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Seating</TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Actors</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">Action</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">11:00 am - 12:30 pm</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">SMTWTHFSA</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">Showplace Cinemas</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">Aug 20, 2014 - Sept 12, 2014</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">TBA</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">Zach Galifinakis (<ABBR title= "Primary">P</ABBR>)  target="Zach Galifinakis" ></TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
```

Here is what I have been trying(courtesy of Praveen from another one of my question's [Extract Text from BR tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289689/extract-text-from-br-tags/24304177#24304177)):

```
 WebElement table =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='datadisplaytable']"));
   WebElement tbody=table.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));
   List<WebElement> rows=tbody.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
   System.out.println("Row  size:"+rows.size());
   ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

   for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++)
   {
     WebElement column = tbody.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='datadisplaytable']/tbody/tr[2]/td"));
     if(column.getText().trim().contains("."))
     {
        System.out.println("text : "+column.getText().trim());
        list.add(column.getText().trim());
     }

   }
```

I am also able to get the table information in a string, but I need to keep each table element separate. I could use substrings but information varies, so the string length varies too. Should I use xpath to extract the information, or is there another way?

Comment: Is that really the actual HTML? Seems invalid.

Comment: No, but its an example of what it is. The webpage is large and if I was to post the entire thing it would be too long, and to shorten it I would have to cut and paste it in a way that it would be invalid anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to grab the first table information by using

```
WebElement movieinfo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='datadisplaytable']/descendant::table["+tcounter+"]//td[1]"));
```

with tcounter being an int value = 1.

I then changed the value of td[1] to grab other cells and incremented the value of tcounter to access the other tables. It's not very pretty but it works. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume I understand your question correctly. You want to read the names of the movies from all the tables present in the webpage.

1. read all the tables
2. Loop them and in each row of the table, get the second column (assumed to have movie name)

I have not tested this in my machine.. This is the code which you can try.

```
List<WebElement> tables = driver.findElements(By.className("ddtitle"));

foreach(WebElement table : tables){

   List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("TR"));

   foreach(WebElement row : rows){
       WebElement movieName = row.findElements(By.tagName("TD")).get(2); // column # in row
       System.out.println(movieName);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey Purus, thanks for taking the time to help out. I've tried your code but I am getting an error that says, "the method findElements(By) is undefined for the type List<WebElement>. This occurs at the line movieName = tables.findElements... any ideas?

Comment: Updated the code.. there was some issue.. please retry.

Comment: New error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Comment: ArrayList is referred to which object?

Comment: I'm not sure what I changed but the error doesn't occur anymore. Now it stays running but doesn't pull anything up. I am able to bring up the first table cell (action) by using:      WebElement info = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='datadisplaytable']//tbody//td//td[1]")); If there was some way I could use xpath to grab the first cell of the second table I could solve my problem that way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your XPath expression restricting *the context* of the selected tables by using the preceding `<TR>` to distinguish each table). This expression, for example, would only select the *second* table:

```
//table[@class='datadisplaytable'][preceding-sibling::th[1]='MovieTwo']/tbody/tr[2]/td
```

(assuming that the movie titles are different)

The expression `//table/preceding-sibling:th[1]` selects the nearest preceding `<th>` element. Its *context* is formed by all tables that have a `class` attribute `datadisplaytable`. The predicate further restricts that set to only those `table` elements which have a preceding `<th>` containing the string value `'MovieTwo'`.

If you know the names of several movies, you can use a variable in the place of the movie name,  and loop through each table individually, choosing the ones you wish to process.

Comment: Thanks for the response. For me this solution is a problem because I am going over multiple webpages of movies, and I don't know how many movies are in a page. The first page may have two movies, but the next could have ten, the one after could have four, and so on. I have code that puts each movie title from a page in a list, so is there a way I could have it search through the movie list index and get the relevant info that goes with each title?

Comment: This is *one* way to select one table. If you can find other invariant blocks, text, ids, etc, that you can use as an *anchor* to create a *context*, you can write an expression *from that context* to the node you want to select.

Comment: Interesting...would it be possible to use movie titles as context, then use a loop that matches the title in my array list the table header text, and if they match proceed to extract the data? Will xpath allow me to do that? Just wondering if you know off the top of your head. I'll play around with it and see if I can get it to work. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Since the movie titles can be used to anchor your context (via the `preceding-sibling::` axis), then you can always select the table *relative* to it. You can select almost anything you want. Ex: select the table after a table, the table number 2 (using a positional predicate [2]), or a preceding::table[2] (2 tables above), and so on.

Comment: I was able to use this code:
WebElement movieInfo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='datadisplaytable']//tbody//td//td[1]")); and retrieve Action. How would I go about selecting the next table from here? I have tried preceding-sibling and preceding::table[2] and even [@class='datadisplaytable'][2] any other suggestions?

Comment: I mentioned those cases as examples of what you *could* do. It depends on what you want to select. In my answer I showed you how you could select a single table, even if it had the same class name.

Comment: The *predicate* is used to *restrict* a context or a selection. In your case you need to restrict the *context* of all tables with that class name, so you add the predicate (which can contain any boolean expression) *after* `//table[@class='datadisplaytable']`.